# Question in solution of a problem whose answer equals to Catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, sequence-of-function, catalan-numbers

I am trying questions from Richard Brualdi Introductory Combinatorics and I am unable to think about this question of Exercise 8.6 .

I am studying combinatorices from Richard Brualdi.

> Question is ->Let 2n equally spaced points on a circle be chosen. Show  that number of ways to join these points 
>   in pairs so that  resulting n line segments don't intersect equal nth Catalan number.

I was unable to think about the question . So, looked at hints whose image I am posting. (See Question 1 ch8) . I have no question in first 3 lines of hint but I am unable to deduce how the restrictions on choosing Q gives the desired recurrence relation.

> Can someone please give hints to get the required recurrence relation with the help of the arguments given in question ?

I shall be really thankful.

[image]

Comment: I guess each term of the sum, say $a_ia_{n-i-1}$, is due to the case where $2i$ points are on one side of the line connecting $P$ and $Q$, and the other $2n-2i-2$ are on the other side.

Comment: @dfnu  you are right thanks!!